# Are there programming tasks you consider so critical that you always do them thoughtfully and slowly?

Tags: task

There are some tasks, especially the ones that involve deleting folders as SU, that I do thoughtfully and slowly before I press the Enter key. I think if others saw me do these at the careful pace that I do they would cringe. Are there critical programming tasks that you perform that you believe deserve this thoughtful and careful consideration?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Changes to live databases, actually I do a backup first just in case even know I'm extra careful :)

Answer (score 12):

It's kind of a programming task, because if I do it wrong, it will affect my ability to get paid for programming:  Write emails on touchy subjects or to touchy people.

It can take me an hour to get the tone of a one paragraph email just right.

Comment: And it takes less than a second for somebody to misinterpret the tone anyway. :)

Answer (score 5):

Anything that irrecoverably changes important data. I've learned my lesson the hard way, several times.

Answer (score 4):

A release process is usually a methodical thing for me.

Answer (score 4):

Everything. I've never been a "just dive into it" programmer. Always have, always will be.

Answer (score 1):

Submits - 'cause its embarrassing if I break a test.

Answer (score 1):

Code to evaluate the accuracy of something I'm developing.  Otherwise, I spend all this time making the other code production-ready, only to find it doesn't compute the right thing after all.

Answer (score 0):

Common code.  I.e. changes to old, shared code which is used in multiple independent programs.

Answer (score 0):

Doing **get** from SourceSafe — really easy to hit a wrong button and lose your local version that you've been working on.
/I hate SS, but am forced to use it./

Answer (score 0):

Kernel driver stuff - cause those blue screens are a pain !

Answer (score 0):

Any collection juggling, especially in C (all it takes is one off by one error to shotgun your heap).

Answer (score 0):

On the DB side, if I run an update/insert/delete and I don't want to backup the whole database, I always `select * into myTable_backup from myTable`

Answer (score 0):

if make big changes in Visual Studio eg a big refactoring or maybe re-organising solution\project structure I will do it on a copy of solution first to see if there are any gotcha and that the bloody thing will still compile and play nice. Once satisfied this is the case I will do it on code under source control.

I do this because I have experienced situations where the 'rollback' functionality of whatever source control you are using won't let you rollback as required and\or does not get it %100.